# Type X does not inherit from Y

Tags: ios, generics, swift, associated-types

The following Swift code yields this error on the last line: `Type 'E' does not inherit from 'C<Self>'`. Not sure what's going on here. Any clues would be appreciated.

```
class C<T> {}

protocol P {
  typealias E : C<Self>
}

class A : P {
  typealias E = C<A>
}

class S<U : P> {}
class C2<T> : S<A> {}
```

**Update: I simplified the broken example.** The old version (to which milos' answer refers) can be found in this question's edit history.

Comment: You did a good job of simplifying the code. While you are at it, you may as well improve the title... something along the lines of: "Recursive type definitions in Swift", or "Associated types constrained in terms of Self", or something like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have renamed your identifiers so I can think about them:

```
protocol P {
    typealias E : C<Self>
}

class A : P {
    typealias E = C1<Any>
}

class B : P {
    typealias E = C2<Any>
}

class C<T> {}
class C1<T> : C<A> {}

class S<T, U : P> : C<T> {} // <-- mark!
class C2<T> : S<B, A> {}
```

This should eventually, and very nearly does, work out. In effect, what you want is:

```
class B : P {
    typealias E = C<B> // which is what P requires (same with class A)
}
```

However, on the marked line, where you are defining `class S` you are asking the compiler to check the type of `U : P` and then pass `B` as the concrete type to check. Unfortunately, at this point `B`'s conformance to `P` is still unresolved (i.e. it is itself defined in terms of `C2 : S : C`, which is where you are going with `U : P`). Removing `: P` in `U : P` removes the error, though this may not be what you want. Then again, depending on what you want, there may be any number of solutions :)

**EDIT**

The following is in response to @igul222's much simplified code example. I still, think, however, that the compiler is simply returning a less then helpful error message, which is really caused by the recursive type definition. Consider, for example, if you define an `enum` in terms of itself:

```
enum E {
    case C(E) // error: recursive value type 'E' is not allowed
}
```

Now, this is probably also the problem with the following:

```
class C<T> {}

protocol P {
    typealias E : C<Self>
    var c: E { get }
}

final class A : P {
    typealias E = C<A>
    var c: E { return E() }
}
// --> error: type 'A' does not conform to protocol 'P'
// --> note: protocol requires property 'c' with type 'E'
// --> note: candidate has non-matching type 'E'
```

... neither does this work (a version of your gist):

```
class C<T> {}

protocol P {
    typealias E : C<Self>
}

final class A : P {
    typealias E = C<A>
}

class X<U : P> {}

X<A>() // --> error: type 'E' does not inherit from 'C<`Self`>'
```

... or this:

```
class C<T> {}

protocol P {
    typealias E : C<Self>
}

final class A : P {
    typealias E = C<A>
}

let a = A()

func f<T: P>(T) {}

f(a) // --> error: 'A' is not identical to '`Self`'
```

What the compiler seems to be saying is that  `Self` in `C<Self>` is not yet `A`, i.e. that `A` is not yet it`Self` since to be `A` it must conform to `P` which is in turn pending `C<Self>` checking out... But the following works because `A` no longer defines an associated type in terms of itself:

```
class C<T> {}

protocol P {
    var c: C<Self> { get }
}

final class A : P {
    typealias E = C<A> // just a typealias, no longer an associated type
    var c: E { return E() }
}
```

Some patterns of functional programming require recursively defined types, so it might be nice to have that in Swift. At present, however, I am not sure one can usefully conform to a protocol with an associated type of the form `T<Self>`, even though the compiler allows its definition... otherwise, this should all just work at runtime.

### EDIT 2

I have just upgraded to **Xcode 6.1 GM Seed** and things have changed! The following snippet, that would not have compiled before, now compiles and appears to run fine!

```
protocol A {
    var b: B? { get set }
}

protocol B {
    var a: A? { get set }
}

class Ca: A {
    var b: B?
}

class Cb: B {
    var a: A?
}

let a = Ca()    // --> {nil}
let b = Cb()    // --> {nil}

a.b = b         // --> {{{...}}}
b.a = a         // --> {{{...}}}
```

This improvement, however, does not extend to recursively defined associated types.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I managed to reduce the problem down to this code, which doesn't involve B (and is generally much simpler, giving the real problem less room to hide). Mind taking a second look? https://gist.github.com/igul222/2aff849d0ddc95f21da7

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied sooner (we are probably in a different timezone). I have updated the answer in response to your gist.

Comment: The revised version of the answers sound like the correct explanation to me. Although I can't see why it shouldn't be possible to write something like this. So it might be worth a bug report.

Comment: I think Apple is well aware of this. There is plenty of evidence that they are planning to faze in more functional features over time. In the meantime, however, I sympathise with the compiler team: imagine writing a type checker for all the possible implementations of your protocol!